# Square of a uniform random variable

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables

> Let $X$ be a random variable that follows $Uniform(-1,2)$ distribution.
>   Then what will be the cdf of $X^2$?

What i did was
$$P(X^2\le y)=P(X\le y^{0.5})= \int_{-1}^{y^{0.5}}(1/3)dx=(1/3)(y^{0.5}+1) $$ $0\lt y \lt 4$
But this cdf doesnt give the probability $0$ at $y=0$ also the pdf which i get doesn't integrate to 1
What is wrong can somebody explain??
Am i doing something wrong??

Comment: I know it should be $|X|\lt y^{0.5}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

Discern the following cases:

- $y<0$
- $0\leq y<1$ then $X^2\leq y\iff -y^{0.5}\leq X\leq y^{0.5}$
- $1\leq y<4$ then $X^2\leq y\iff-1\leq X\leq y^{0.5}$
- $y\geq4$

Comment: drab how do this occur to you that we have to deal with these cases it never strikes to me

Comment: Do you understand and agree with the mentioned iff statements?

Comment: Yes i agree with you on them

Comment: And are you capable to apply this in order to find the CDF? How the split up in these cases comes to mind is on one hand straightforward, but - I admit - on the other hand also a matter of mathematical maturity. I have seen lot's of questions like this in my life, and that will probably be different for you.

Comment: Yes now i am able to find the cdf..and thnxx

Comment: You are very welcome.